# How to transform an expression tree (AST) into DOM tree (XML)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, abstract-syntax-tree

I need to allow a user to write expressions and build XML tree from the expression. My plan is to use `math.js` which parses and generates an [expression tree](https://mathjs.org/docs/expressions/expression_trees.html#expression-trees), **then convert that expression tree into DOM tree**, and then convert DOM tree into XML using [XMLSerializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLSerializer). The part in bold is tricky one.

For the expression:

```
const node = math.parse('sqrt(2 + x)')
```

`math.js` generates the following expression tree:

```
 FunctionNode    sqrt
                   |
  OperatorNode     +
                  / \
  ConstantNode   2   x   SymbolNode
```

Now I need to convert it to DOM. I'd like to use the traversal API exposed by the library. They have `traverse` method, that recursively traverse all nodes in a node tree and executes given callback for this node and each of its child nodes. The `path` parameter in the callback is a string containing a relative JSON Path.

My first attempt that included keeping a reference to the parent DOM node didn't work as expected:

```
const parent = new DocumentFragment();
let tmpParent = parent;

  const node = math.parse('3 * x + 2');
  node.traverse(function(node, path, parent) {
    switch (node.type) {
      case 'OperatorNode':
        const operator = document.createElement('div');
        tmpParent.appendChild(operator);
        tmpParent = operator;
        break;
      case 'ConstantNode':
        const constant = document.createElement('span');
        tmpParent.appendChild(constant);
        tmpParent = constant;
      ...
    }
  });
```

So I started looking at how [HAST is transformed into JSX](https://github.com/mdx-js/mdx/blob/main/packages/mdx/mdx-hast-to-jsx.js#L85), and they use the following approach:

```
walk(estree, {
    enter: function(node) {
      stack.push();
      ...
    }
    leave: function(node) {
      ...
        stack.pop();
      }
    }
  })
```

So I gather I'd need to somehow use **stack** as well. But their pattern exposes `enter` and `leave` callback points, while with `traverse` from `math.js` I have only a single point.

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to achieve with a single point using stack or else how to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extend the node object with a custom property like `DOM` and append children to the `DOM` of the parent node:

```js
const node = math.parse('sqrt(2 + x)')

node.traverse(function(node, path, parent) {
    switch (node.type) {
      case 'FunctionNode':
        node.DOM = document.createElement('div')
        break
      case 'OperatorNode':
        node.DOM = document.createElement('p');
        break;
      case 'ConstantNode':
        node.DOM = document.createElement('span');
        break;
      case 'SymbolNode':
        node.DOM = document.createElement('b');
        break
    }
    
    if (parent)
      parent.DOM.appendChild(node.DOM)

});
  
console.log(node.DOM.outerHTML)
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/mathjs@9.4.2/lib/browser/math.js"></script>
```

Comment: hah, true, an interesting idea!  I upvoted your answer and will accept a bit later if nobody will suggest a better solution. One caveat is that it requires that nodes be mutable, which luckily is the case with `math.js`. Or I can probably define a Map (astNode->domNode) and simply retrieve corresponding DOM node. What do you think? I was curios to solve this problem using stack which I showed [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67900765/2545680) but it appears that using stack always needs `enter` and `leave` callbacks.

Comment: a cleaner way would be not to use `traverse` and walk the tree with your own function, to which you can simply pass the parent DOM node.

Comment: yeah :) so am I right that with just a single callback point I won't be able to use `stack`?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it like this using `forEach` method available on each node and `stack` idea from the `HAST/JSX` conversion code I referenced in my question:

```
const parent = new DocumentFragment();
const stack = [];

function _traverse(node, buildDomNode, dom) {
    // this is equivalent to `enter` callback
    stack.push(dom);

    node.forEach(function(child, path, parent) {
      let d = buildDomNode(child, path, parent, dom);
      _traverse(child, buildDomNode, d);
    });

    // this is equivalent to `leave` callback
    stack.pop();
}

const node = math.parse('3 * x + 2');
const dnode = buildDomNode(node, null, null, parent);
stack.push(dnode);

_traverse(node, buildDomNode, dnode);

function buildDomNode(node, path, parent, dom) {
    let dnode;

    switch (node.type) {
      case 'OperatorNode':
        dnode = document.createElement('div');
        break;
      case 'ConstantNode':
        dnode = document.createElement('span');
        ...
    }

    dom.appendChild(dnode);
    return dnode;
  }
```